# Multiple Sets of Measure Names with Filters - Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am newbie in Tableau and I want to do a very specific viz. Please refer to the image -

[image: Visualization Question]

As you can observe, there are 2 'Measure Values' in the 'Row' Section.

What I want to achieve is to apply a different set of filters to the first 'Measure Values' and a different filter to the second 'Measure Values' and stack the graphs side by side.

I am actively looking of Google for the solution, but I am unable to find any.

Any help/lead will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create a worksheet with one of the measures in your row column, then duplicate and create a second worksheet with the second measure from your row column.

2) On the second worksheet, apply the second set of filters that you want.

3) Create a dashboard, and stack them similar to how they are in the worksheet but on the dashboard.

Your users will not know they are looking at a "dashboard" -- to them it will look like a worksheet.

This is the **ONLY** way to do what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Create two sheets saperately with required filters and then place two sheets side by side in dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, but I want them side by side stacked bars. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is your filtering both the charts

Answer (score 0):

Tableau filters are applicable to complete sheet not measure specific.
though you can create different calculative fields with filter included in itself OR you can just duplicate the sheet and use different filters in each field as per requirement.